# Prolog difference lists: code works on SWI and GNU Prolog, but not Yap

Tags: prolog, yap

This code correctly calculates the number of elements in a difference list when I run it on GNU Prolog and SWI Prolog. However, Yap enters an infinite loop.

```
count(X-X1,0) :- unify_with_occurs_check(X,X1), !.
count([H|T]-T1,N) :- count(T-T1,M), N is M+1.

?- count([1,2|A]-A,N).
```

Why would a Prolog interpreter (like Yap) not terminate when asked this query?

Comment: I tried your code in Yap 6.2.2 and it worked fine. `?- count([1,2|A]-A,N). N = 2`

Comment: @gusbro falls in loop in yap 5.1.3: trace: `?- count([1,2|A]-A,N).
          (1)    call:count([1,2|_1059]-_1059,_1063) ? 
          (1)    redo:count([1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,...]-_1059,_1063) ? 
          (2)    call:count([2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,...]-_1059,_1147) ? 
          (2)    redo:count([2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,...]-_1059,_1147) ?`

Comment: Hm, I'm using 5.1.3, so it could be a fixed bug...

Comment: I have just installed Yap 6.2.3 and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @gusbro: you have actually answered the question, so it would be nice if you posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in Yap 5.1.3

Newer versions (tested with Yap 6.2.2) work fine:

```
?- count([1,2|A]-A,N).
   N = 2
```